# Defining a string as in fprintf syntax

Tags: c, string

How to build up a **string in C that includes parameters**? Is there a way similar to `fprintf` syntax to do it? For example here's a little `testProg.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   printf("You are running %s program.\n", argv[0]);
   // It will print: "You are running testProg.c program.\n"
   char myString[];
   // I want the string printed by printf to be saved inside myString[]
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `snprintf`. First determine the buffer size for `myString` that will fit the content. Then use `snprintf` to fill in the content.

```
char myString[100] = "";
snprintf( myString, sizeof(myString), "You are running %s program.", argv[0] );
```

`snprintf` is similar to `fprintf` (which is the general version of `printf` with the output stream being `stdout`), so all control formats applied - details can be found in the standard:

> 7.21.6.5 The snprintf function

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
          const char * restrict format, ...);
```

Comment: It looks like that is exactly what I was looking for! Isn't there a way to use the exact size needed instead of using `100` as size of the array? Thanks!

Comment: you need to allocate the buffer size anyway (either statically or dynamically) - for such simple case static buffer would be suffice

Comment: If you want to use dynamic or VLA allocation: `snprintf` returns the number of characters written. If the string is truncated, it returns the number of characters that would have been written had the buffer been large enough. It is legal to pass `NULL` as buffer when the size is 0, so you can call `n = snprintf(NULL, 0, ...)` first, allocate `n + 1` bytes and then call `snprintf` again with the buffer and its correct size.